# Custom progressdialog in android created dynamically

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I've created progressdialog in asynctask dynamically. I use custom style for my app. when I did that my progressdialog style changed to white color i need my default style in black with white text.

My java file:

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
    this.dialog.show();
}

 // my prog

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
        }}
```

My style.xml :

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar</item>

</style>
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Comment: then create another `Theme` for your `Progress Dialog` and set like `ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this, R.style.MyTheme);`

Comment: Why this line is not working <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar</item>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the below line to pass the `style` through your constructor...

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
```

to this...

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this, R.style.ProgressBar);
```

**Update:**

I just change the `style` as below...and its working for.

```
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I need default theme black backgroung and text in white. with this line.
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar</item>

Comment: Now, which color you are getting?

Comment: white backgorund and text.

Comment: its working for me correctly...**White text and Black background**. Clean your project then run again.

Comment: Yeah this way is working fine but y couldn't I use this way <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar</item>

Comment: <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner</item> This is working but not progressbarstyle

Comment: @HamidShatu Help me bro I'm stuck from yesterday.

Comment: Why you are setting `@color/red` and `@color/green` when you are trying to set `Wite` and `black`?

Comment: No change it. I want it like the one in holo theme

Comment: oh, man...I tried so hard...but could not achieve what you are desiring to do...I give up. Sorry buddy.

Comment: No, it's not working. You get the default color and background, not what you set in the style.

Comment: @HamidShatu, I am trying run your snippet of code you mentioned above as i am trying to make a custom progressbar, I do get black background with white text, but progress dialog is shown at top - left corner of the screen, please tell me why this is so and is there a way to customize gravity of the custom progressbar as i want it to be at center of the screen