# Android: Having a custom Theme on whole application

Tags: android, dialog, themes, manifest

I have a theme which have set as yellow background and assigned to application level in the manifest file. When I try doing custom progress dialog I have a background rectangle yellow. How do I overcome with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've founded a topic on StackOverflow, which might be very useful for you:

[Change style of ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077035/change-style-of-progressdialog)

There you would find this answer

> You can style your progress dialog this way:  create a drawable file
>   with your ring shape (circular_progress_dialog)
>
> ```
> <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:fromDegrees="270"
> android:toDegrees="270">
> <shape
>     android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
>     android:shape="ring"
>     android:thickness="2dp"
>     android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->
>
>     <gradient
>         android:angle="0"
>         android:endColor="@color/main_background"
>         android:startColor="@color/main_orange"
>         android:type="sweep"
>         android:useLevel="false" />
> </shape> </rotate>
> ```
>
> one to style your progress bar
>
> ```
>  <style name="ProgressBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
>     <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
>     <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
>     <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
>     <item name="android:background">@color/transparency_pleca</item>
>     <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/circular_progress_dialog</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> Notice your "android:indeterminateDrawable" property
>
> Yout can set your style with
>
> ```
> myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.ProgressBar)
> ```

If it's not satisfying you, read also:

[Custom progressdialog in android created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217673/custom-progressdialog-in-android-created-dynamically)

[How to customize the Progress Dialog in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900017/how-to-customize-the-progress-dialog-in-android)

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Create a new theme for dialogs where you change the background. Then use the `Dialog` constructor passing the style.

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Create the dialog like this.

```
new Dialog(context, R.style.Dialog);
```